# 4000 inputs in where condition with multiple OR hits query performance in PostgresSQL and Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, performance

```
SELECT
           some 25 columns from all tables a to h
   FROM
           a,
           b,
           c,
           d,
           e
           LEFT JOIN f ON f.id=d.id,
           g,
           h,
           i,
           j,
           k
    WHERE
           a.id_1 = b.id_2
            AND b.id_2 = c.id_3
            AND c.id_3 = d.id_4
            AND d.id_4 = e.id_5
            AND e.id_5 = f.id_6
            AND f.id_6 = g.id_7
            AND g.id_7 = h.id_8
            AND h.id_8 = i.id_9
            AND i.id_9 = j.id_10
            AND j.id_11 = k.id_12
            AND ((d.id_4 IN 
            (1000 inputs) OR d.id_4 IN (1000 inputs) OR d.id_4 IN (1000 inputs) OR d.id_4 IN (1000 inputs)))
            AND a.x='some text'
            AND  b.y LIKE 'some text%'
    ORDER BY
           some_column DESC
```

Above is the query and it takes around 12 min to execute and when the d.id_4 where with 4000 inputs removed, query returns result in few seconds.

How can this query can be rewritten to get the best performance. Here id_4 is the primary key in table d.

When i club all 4000 inputs in one query without multiple OR, i get in 2 min.

But my requirement is to support this query in both postgres and oracle.

So i was supposed to split input into 1000s and do OR condition of 1000s. Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Comment: Create a temp table using `WITH` clause for values in `IN` condition. and use `join` instead of `IN`

Comment: `WITH IN_A AS (SELECT 1,2... .FROM DUAL) , IN_B AS (SELECT a,b,c, from DUAL) SELECT ... FROM MAIN_TABLE  JOIN IN_A JOIN IN_B

Comment: Where do these 4000 inputs come from? Somebody typing them in by hand? I doubt it. So please explain how this query is called and where the data comes from.

Comment: @bngk . . . Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @APC first apache lucene search happens in the process and that apache lucene output is the 4000 values becomes input to this query

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, its a old code written in 2007 with custom ORM actually. Will refactor it. Thanks

Comment: FYI, Oracle once had a limit of 1000 items in an "in" list... not sure if it still does, but it's a reasonable limit because it's death to compile a statement that large and it's a way of forcing you to use a join instead.  So my point is if you put all 4,000 items in the temp table per @DigvijayS suggestion, you don't need the "or" conditions -- it would simply be a single join.  And it *should* run much faster and will be much more DB friendly.

Comment: 1000 is still the limit in Oracle and rewriting the joins won't help the performance

Comment: For running against Oracle I doubt there will be any advantage to using a common table expression instead of lists of values.  (If CTEs magically solved so many performance problems, then why wouldn't the optimizer simply re-write everything to use a CTE?)  Large `IN` lists themselves aren't a problem (until you get to like a million), but they may indirectly affect the optimizer estimates.  It's probably more important to focus on how the execution plan changes when the lists of values change.